# Static wxRichTextControl?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, richtext

I want to create an Help page for my wxWidgets application, which consists of only text of various fonts, sizes and colors. I tried achieving that with `wxStaticText`'s and sizers but I was having trouble so I switched to a `wxRichTextCtrl`, which I like to use. The problem is, the text should of course be non-modifiable. I know of the existance of the wxRE_READONLY flag, but it doesn't hide the caret that appears when I click on the text.

Isn't there some kind of `wxRichStaticTextCtrl` that works exactly like a `wxRichTextCtrl`, but is readonly by default and doesn't have this problem? I tried looking online, but to no avail.

Comment: what is the problem with creating wxTextCtrl as read-only and supplying wxTE_RICH{2} style flag? OTOH, it is very weird chouice given that wxWidgets support multiple Help frameworks...

Comment: It's (probably) showing the caret so the user can select and copy text from the control, even though they can't change it. If you don't want that, you probably want to disable the control instead of just making it read-only.

Comment: @Igor What do you mean? Wouldn't the problem still persist using a wxTextCtrl?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin the disable solution worked for me, thanks.

Comment: @giorgio_developer, the disable control has only one color - grey. So, I'm curious - how come it works for you?

Comment: I don't know, the colors in the control seem unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for "rich" static text is `wxHtmlWindow`: this allows you to just define your help contents in terms of simple HTML which is usually more than enough.